# Terraform: How to add subnet mask after concat variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, amazon-vpc, devops-services

How I can add /32 subnet mask to output of concat variable which returns 3 ip addresses to me?

My small fraction of code like this:

`nat_ips      = concat(data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip)`

And when I try apply this, I have error about **invalid CIDR address**.

Then my question is: How I can add into my concat subnetmask to all output addresses?

This is not work:

```
  #nat_ips      = "concat(${data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip/32})"
  #nat_ips      = "${concat(data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip)}"
  #nat_ips      = "concat(${data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip})/32"
  #nat_ips      = "${concat(data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip)}/32"
  #nat_ips      = concat(data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip)/32
```

Comment: not sure why do you need to pass `/32` as CIDR this means a single IP! It will be helpful if you can paste some code snippet!

Comment: I need to add a subnet mask because it is required to add IP address in Security Group in AWS. Unfortunately, I can't insert the code because it is made up of many dependent segments. The key element is right here and exactly how I can add to this command that each IP address will receive a subnet mask.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I have solution for my answer.

```
nat_ips       = "${formatlist("%s/32", concat(data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ips.*.public_ip))}"
```